# What am I doing wrong in Swift for calling this Objective-C block/API call?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, swift, ios8

I'm using [RedditKit](https://github.com/samsymons/RedditKit) to integrate Reddit into an app, and in Objective-C I called the API as follows (and it worked fine):

```
    [[RKClient sharedClient] signInWithUsername:@"username" password:@"password" completion:^(NSError *error) {
        RKPagination *pagination = [RKPagination paginationWithLimit:100];
        [[RKClient sharedClient] linksInSubredditWithName:subredditSelected pagination:pagination completion:^(NSArray *collection, RKPagination *pagination, NSError *error) {
             // code that executes on completion
        }];
    }];
```

Here's how I'm calling it in Swift:

```
RKClient.sharedClient().signInWithUsername("username", password: "password", completion: { (error: NSError!) in
    RKClient.sharedClient().frontPageLinksWithPagination(RKPagination(limit: 50), completion: { (collection: RKLink[]!, pagination: RKPagination!, error: NSError!) in
        // code that executes on completion
    })
})
```

But I keep getting this error with the Swift version:

> Could not find an overload for 'init' that accepts the supplied arguments

EDIT: Here's an example project showing it: http://cl.ly/3K0i2P1r3j1y

Comment: Maybe try to make use of type inference for your closure. just leave out the types and have `(collection, pagination, error) in`

Comment: @Doug also this  :)  there is no need to include the types here for the arguments to the completion block, those types are inferred by the methods signature

Comment: @JackWu Unfortunately that didn't help either.

Comment: Added an example project.

Comment: @DougSmith Thanks for the project! Found the issue for you :p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Note**: This issue is the same as in these questions:

[animateWithDuration:animations:completion: in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24296023/animatewithdurationanimationscompletion-in-swift/24297018#24297018)

[Properly referencing self in dispatch_async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24347261/properly-referencing-self-in-dispatch-async/24347521#24347521)

---

Thanks for adding the example project, the issue is as follows:

From the Swift book: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Closures.html

One of the optimizations of Closures is:

> Implicit returns from single-expression closures

So... the compiler thinks your closure is returning a value of `NSURLSessionDataTask` because it is the only line inside the closure block, thus changing the type of the argument.

There are a few ways to solve this, none that are ideal...

The idea is that any other line you add into the closure will fix it, so this will literally work:

```
      RKClient.sharedClient().signInWithUsername("username", password: "password", completion: { error -> () in
            let a = 1
            RKClient.sharedClient().frontPageLinksWithPagination(nil, completion: nil)
        })
```

A slightly cleaner way to solve this would be:

```
RKClient.sharedClient().signInWithUsername("username", password: "password", completion: { error in
    let client = RKClient.sharedClient()
    client.frontPageLinksWithPagination(nil, completion: nil)
})
```

This wouldn't be an issue if you simply had more code to put into that closure as well!

Comment: You can add `return Void()` at the end of your closure.  Now you have two statements and the return value matches the expected type.

Answer (score 0):

It probably doesn't like your `RKLink[]!` type for `collection` as `NSArray` can theoretically contain any type of object.  Try making collection an `Array<AnyObject>!` or just an `NSArray!` to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness here's some code that works:

```
    RKClient.sharedClient().frontPageLinksWithPagination(nil, completion: {
        (collection, pagination, error) in
        if let links = collection as? RKLink[] {
            for link in links {
                println(link.title)
            }
        }
    })
```