# Properly referencing self in dispatch_async

Tags: ios, closures, swift

How do I properly reference self in a swift closure?

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

I get the error:

`Cannot convert the expression's type 'Void' to type 'UIViewController!"`

Randomly I tried:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { ()
    self.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

and it worked. Not sure what the extra () does! Anyone care to explain? Thanks!

Comment: Accept the anwer if it is correct, and upvote it if it went above and beyond your expectations.

Answer (score 4):

This is the same issue as people have run in with these questions:

[What am I doing wrong in Swift for calling this Objective-C block/API call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24338842/what-am-i-doing-wrong-in-swift-for-calling-this-objective-c-block-api-call/24347498#24347498)

[animateWithDuration:animations:completion: in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24296023/animatewithdurationanimationscompletion-in-swift/24297018#24297018)

Here is the general idea:

From the Swift book: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Closures.html

One of the optimizations of Closures is:

> Implicit returns from single-expression closures

Thus, if you just have one line in your closure, your closure's return value changes. In this case, `popViewController` returns the view controller being popped. By adding `()` to the closure, you just made it a 2-line closure and the return value isn't implicit anymore!

Comment: I'm unsure if this counts as a duplicate question due to them having the same issue. If it does, please flag!

Answer (score 0):

I answered something like this a couple of days ago for a related issue re: Swift's 'implicit return value for single-expression closure': [animateWithDuration:animations:completion: in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24296023/animatewithdurationanimationscompletion-in-swift/24297018#24297018)

In this case, the method `popViewControllerAnimated` returns the UIViewController that was popped from the stack: (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/popViewControllerAnimated:)

Even though you aren't explicitly doing anything with the return value of that method, Swift is using that value (the returned UIViewController) as the return value for the closure - however, the closure is expecting a return value of Void.

When you added the extra parens `()`, you essentially added another line to the closure, and since it is no longer a 'single-expression closure' it no longer implicit returns the popped UIViewController.

The community will eventually settle on a convention for handling this, for now when I have been running into it I have been advocating adding `return ()` to the end of the closure (as it clearly states the intention, (1) short circuiting the 'implicit return' by adding another statement, and (2) explicitly returning what was expected).