# UIView.animateWithDuration completion

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewanimation

I have a question concerning the swift implementation of the method mentioned in the title. If I do this:

```
leadingSpaceConstraint.constant = 0
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}, completion: { (complete: Bool) in
    self.navigationController.returnToRootViewController(true)
})
```

I get the following problem: Missing argument for parameter 'delay' in call. This only happens if I have the self.navigationController.returnToRootViewController() in the completion part. If I extract that statement into a seperate method like this:

```
leadingSpaceConstraint.constant = 0
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}, completion: { (complete: Bool) in
    self.returnToRootViewController()
})

func returnToRootViewController() {
    navigationController.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

Then it works perfectly and does exactly what I want. Of course this does not seem to be the ideal solution and more like a work around. Can anyone tell me what I did wrong or why Xcode (beta 6) is behaving this way?

Comment: This has been a common cause of questions for a long time. It always manifests differently...see the answer here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24338842/what-am-i-doing-wrong-in-swift-for-calling-this-objective-c-block-api-call/24347498#24347498

Comment: possible duplicate of [animateWithDuration:animations:completion: in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24296023/animatewithdurationanimationscompletion-in-swift)

Comment: Ha. I knew this had been answered before, but wasn't finding the dupe. (Actually, I'm pretty sure I've answered it before that dupe, but I can't find it in my history either.)

Comment: Try changing `(complete:Bool) in` to `(complete:Bool) -> Void in`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I presume you mean `popToRootViewControllerAnimated` in your first snippet, since `returnToRootViewController` isn't a method on `UUNavigationController`.

Your problem is that `popToRootViewControllerAnimated` has a return value (the array of view controllers removed from the navigation stack). This causes trouble even though you're trying to discard the return value.

When Swift sees a function/method call with a return value as the last line of a closure, it assumes you're using the closure shorthand syntax for implicit return values. (The kind that lets you write things like `someStrings.map({ $0.uppercaseString })`.) Then, because you have a closure that returns something in a place where you're expected to pass a closure that returns void, the method call fails to type-check. Type checking errors tend to produce bad diagnostic messages — I'm sure it'd help if you [filed a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com) with the code you have and the error message it's producing.

Anyhow, you can work around this by making the last line of the closure not be an expression with a value. I favor an explicit `return`:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}, completion: { (complete: Bool) in
    self.navigationController.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
    return
})
```

You can also assign that `popToRootViewControllerAnimated` call to an unused variable or put an expression that does nothing after it, but I think the `return` statement is clearest.

Comment: Did you mean you could use `_ = self.navigationController.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)`? Another possibility: explicitly declare the return type of your closure to be `Void`